# Remove spaces and blank lines from txt files

Tags: powershell

I have a script which is not working:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\test\"
for ($i=0; $i -lt $files.Count; $i++) {
  $outfile = $files[$i].FullName + "out" 
  Get-Content $files[$i].FullName | ? {$_.Trim() -ne "" } | Set-Content $files[$i].FullName
}
```

Error is:

```
Set-Content : The process cannot access the file 'C:\test\ADMINISTRATOR.txt'
because it is being use
At D:\skriptablank.ps1:4 char:63
+     Get-Content $files[$i].FullName | ? {$_.Trim() -ne "" } | Set-Content $files ...
+                                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-Content], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetContentCommand
```

What do you think, where I am doing it wrong?

Comment: your script should be ok, like the error states the file is locked by another process. do you maybe have the txt file open in notepad?

Comment: do you want to replace the file or do you want to store it as filename.extension.out?

Comment: Nope, I'm just using chrome.. I assume that, while the program in one txt file, somehow it is trying to open another, and then the error comes up..maybe Im wrong..

Comment: @jisaak I want to replace the files..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `Get-Content` and `Set-Content` on the same file in a pipeline:

```
Get-Content $files[$i].FullName | ... | Set-Content $files[$i].FullName
```

When you do this, the file is usually still being read from when `Set-Content` starts writing to it, thus causing the error you observed. You need to either finish reading before you start writing:

```
(Get-Content $files[$i].FullName) | ... | Set-Content $files[$i].FullName
```

or write to a temporary file first and then replace the original file with the temp file:

```
Get-Content $files[$i].FullName | ... | Set-Content "$env:TEMP\foo.txt"
Move-Item "$env:TEMP\foo.txt" $files[$i].FullName -Force
```

For small files you normally want to use the first approach, because reading the entire file into memory instead of reading it line-by-line is faster and easier to handle.

For large files you normally want to use the second approach in order to avoid memory exhaustion. Make sure to create the temp file on the same filesystem as the file you want to replace, so you don't have to copy the entire data again when moving the temp file (move operations within a filesystem/volume just need to change the reference to the file, which is significantly faster than shifting the file's content).

Comment: Thank you! It's working. So, the good habit is to create edits in some temp folder and then "overwrite it"?